# Understanding microcontroller ADC input pins (atmega328)

Tags: adc, atmega, pullup, floating

If I set up the `ADC` on the `ATmega328` to read from a certain `ADC` pin, what state is the `ADC` pin put in to?

Since I don't explicitly enable any pull ups, is the pin `floating`/`high voltage`/`low voltage`?

Comment: All the GPIO pins on the ATmega328 will be floating until you define it as pull-up, pull-down or output. What purpose serves the ADC input, what is it used for ? Would it be useful to make that input float / pull up / pull down ? Read the ATmega328 datasheet and find out.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The datasheet is quite hard to read from a beginners perspective but I'll try. I'm not sure about which one would be useful: floating doesn't seem right, pull up would cause a constant 5V in my case which doesn't seem right either as the pin would always read 5V so I'm guessing pull downs are used?

Comment: @FakeMoustache if pull downs are used the ADC pins will be at 0V, meaning that if something is at 5V that is connected to the ADC pin then a large current will flow (no resistance), is this correct?

Comment: *floating doesn't seem right* Why not ? It would make perfect sense to me as the ADC is intended to measure an external voltage so you would not want the chip to influence the signal. Perhaps you take floating too literally, the pin is floating but there is also a circuit connected to it which senses the voltage **without loading or influencing the voltage in the pin**

Comment: *if pull downs are used ...is this correct?* No it is not, the pull downs can never cause high currents because that would damage the chip. Before making more assumptions on how this all works I strongly advise you to study some electronics basics because now you're only making wild assumptions.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Pull up and down resistors have always confused me, I am a beginner in electronics, I do agree that I need to improve my electronics knowledge but its difficult when there is so much to understand and I don't really know the terminology that well to search for what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I don't explicitly enable any pull ups, is the pin floating/high voltage/low voltage

The pin state is whatever voltage you are feeding into that pin. If you are feeding in 3V then the pin reads the binary equivalent of 3V. If you feed in 2V then the pin reads the binary equivalent of 2V.

If you don't connect anything to the pin then it is floating.

When working with ADC there is no concept of HIGH or LOW, only discrete quanta of voltages (\$\frac{1}{1024}V_{ref}/LSB\$).

Answer (score 1):

See "Table 18-1. Port Pin Configurations" of Atmega328p complete datasheet. It states clearly that when DDR and PORT registers are zero than the pin is high-impedance.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither HIGH nor LOW. If you want to detect LOW signal, you can enable the the internal pull up resistor by setting PORTx bit to 1. Alternatively, you can use external resistor connected to VCC to detect LOW signal, or external resistor connected to Ground to detect HIGH signal.

Comment: Question title, your answer and your nickname... Up-voted.